# SimpleXML throws XmlPullParserException, unterminated entity ref for no reason

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser

I ran out of ideas on what the problem could be.. I'm using SimpleXML on Android, and it threw the following stacktrace:

```
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281): java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT ????T???????????????...@21:133 in java.io.BufferedReader@b6438630) 
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at com.example.stuff.manager.LevelManager.<init>(LevelManager.java:32)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at com.example.stuff.fragment.MainMenuFragment.onClick(MainMenuFragment.java:138)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT ????T???????????????...@21:133 in java.io.BufferedReader@b6438630) 
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:273)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.error(KXmlParser.java:269)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.pushEntity(KXmlParser.java:781)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.pushText(KXmlParser.java:849)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextImpl(KXmlParser.java:354)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:1378)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader.read(PullReader.java:105)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader.next(PullReader.java:89)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeReader.readElement(NodeReader.java:111)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeReader.readRoot(NodeReader.java:85)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeBuilder.read(NodeBuilder.java:84)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeBuilder.read(NodeBuilder.java:71)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:562)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:462)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at com.example.stuff.manager.LevelManager.<init>(LevelManager.java:27)
06-08 13:20:56.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     ... 12 more
```

Loading from the following XML file:

```
<levels>
<level id="1" time="400">
    <fruitdatas>
        <fruitdata id="2" row="1" column="1"></fruitdata>
        <fruitdata id="0" row="1" column="2"></fruitdata>
        <fruitdata id="3" row="1" column="3"></fruitdata>
        <fruitdata id="4" row="1" column="4"></fruitdata>
    </fruitdatas>
</level>
</levels>
```

And with the following POJOs I made as Containers for the stuff in the XML:

FruitData.java:

```
@Root
public class Fruitdata
{
@Attribute
private Integer id;
@Attribute
private Integer row;
@Attribute
private Integer column;

public Integer getId()
{
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id)
{
    this.id = id;
}
public int getRow()
{
    return row;
}
public void setRow(int row)
{
    this.row = row;
}
public int getColumn()
{
    return column;
}
public void setColumn(int column)
{
    this.column = column;
}
}
```

FruitDatas.java:

```
@Root
public class Fruitdatas
{
@ElementList
private List<Fruitdata> fruitdatas;

public Fruitdatas()
{

}

public Fruitdatas(@ElementList(name = "fruitdatas") List<Fruitdata> fruitdatas)
{
    this.fruitdatas = fruitdatas;
}

public List<Fruitdata> getFruitdatas()
{
    return fruitdatas;
}

public void setFruitdatas(List<Fruitdata> fruitdatas)
{
    this.fruitdatas = fruitdatas;
}
}
```

Level.java:

```
@Root
public class Level
{
@Attribute
private Long id;

@Attribute
private Long time;

@ElementList
private List<Fruitdata> fruitdatas;

public Long getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getTime()
{
    return time;
}

public void setTime(Long time)
{
    this.time = time;
}

public List<Fruitdata> getFruitdatas()
{
    return fruitdatas;
}

public void setFruitdatas(List<Fruitdata> fruits)
{
    this.fruitdatas = fruits;
}   
}
```

Levels.java:

```
@Root
public class Levels
{
@ElementList
private List<Level> levels;

public Levels()
{

}

public Levels(@ElementList(name = "levels") List<Level> levels)
{
    this.levels = levels;
}


public List<Level> getLevels()
{
    return levels;
}

public void setLevels(List<Level> levels)
{
    this.levels = levels;
}
}
```

The loading happens here:

```
public LevelManager()
{
    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    Levels levels = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/xml/levels.xml")));
        levels = serializer.read(Levels.class, br);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error in deserialization.", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (br != null)
        {
            try
            {
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    if (levels != null)
    {
        this.levels = levels.getLevels();
    }
}
```

I also tried it using just the InputStream, but I'm getting the same error.
I've searched for answers, but it was always something being unescaped in the XML. I don't even HAVE any characters that are supposed to be escaped.

I even checked the source code of the xml parser where the exception is thrown, but it was fairly unhelpful:

```
723     private final void More ...pushEntity()
724         throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
725 
726         push(read()); // &
727         
728         
729         int pos = txtPos;
730 
731         while (true) {
732             int c = read();
733             if (c == ';')
734                 break;
735             if (c < 128
736                 && (c < '0' || c > '9')
737                 && (c < 'a' || c > 'z')
738                 && (c < 'A' || c > 'Z')
739                 && c != '_'
740                 && c != '-'
741                 && c != '#') {
742                 if(!relaxed){
743                     error("unterminated entity ref");
744                 }
745                 //; ends with:"+(char)c);           
746                 if (c != -1)
747                     push(c);
748                 return;
749             }
750 
751             push(c);
752         }
753 
754         String code = get(pos);
755         txtPos = pos - 1;
756         if (token && type == ENTITY_REF){
757             name = code;
758         }
759 
760         if (code.charAt(0) == '#') {
761             int c =
762                 (code.charAt(1) == 'x'
763                     ? Integer.parseInt(code.substring(2), 16)
764                     : Integer.parseInt(code.substring(1)));
765             push(c);
766             return;
767         }
768 
769         String result = (String) entityMap.get(code);
770 
771         unresolved = result == null;
772 
773         if (unresolved) {
774             if (!token)
775                 error("unresolved: &" + code + ";");
776         }
777         else {
778             for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
779                 push(result.charAt(i));
780         }
781     }
```

I have no idea what !relaxed means. Therefore, I completely ran out of ideas on how to fix this problem.

Has anyone ran into this before? What could I be doing wrong? I just don't see anything wrong, even my XML is valid. I think I annotated the classes properly, too. Any ideas?

EDIT: Apparently my debug senses were tingling, and I sent the bufferedReader's content through System.out.

Result:

```
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ????T???????????????????????????????????h?????????????????????? ????????????????????????!??????'??????4??????@??????D??????J??????S??????W??????[??????_??????c??????g??????k??????o??????levels??id??time??level??1??400??
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): fruitdatas??        fruitdata??0??row??column??2??4??3??5??6??7??8??9??????$??????????????????????????????????????????????????L???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????$????????????????????????????????????????????????$????????????????????????????????????????????????$??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????$????????????????????    ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????  ????????$????????????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????  ??????????????????????$??????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????????????$??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????$????????????????????  ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????  ????????$??????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ????????????????????????????????????$????????????????????????????????????????????????$??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????$????????????????????   ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????  ????????$????????????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ????????????????????????????????????$????????????????????????????????????????????????$??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????$????????????????????   ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????  ????????$????????????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ????????????????????????????????????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ????????????????????????????????????$????????????????????????????????????????????????$??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????$????????????????????   ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????  ????????$????????????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ????????????????????????????????????$????????????????????????????????????????????????$??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????$?????? ??????????????  ?????????????????????????????????? ?????????????????????????????????????? ??????????????    ????????$??????!??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????!??????????????????????????????????????!??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????"??????????????????????$??????#??????????????????????????????????????????$??????$????????????????????????????????????????????????$??????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ????????????????????????????$??????????????????????$??????%??????????????   ??????????????????????????????????%??????????????????????????????????????%??????????????    ????????$??????&??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????&??????????????????????????????????????&??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????'??????????????????????$??????(??????????????????????????????????????????$??????)????????????????????????????????????????????????)??????????????????????????????????????)??????????????????????$??????*?????????????? ??????????????????????????????????*??????????????????????????????????????*??????????????    ????????$??????+??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????+??????????????????????????????????????+??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????,??????????????????????$??????-??????????????????????????????????????????$??????.????????????????????????????????????????????????.??????????????????????????????????????.??????????????????????$??????/?????????????? ??????????????????????????????????/??????????????????????????????????????/??????????????    ????????$??????0??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????0??????????????????????????????????????0??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????1??????????????????????$??????2??????????????????????????????????????????$??????3????????????????????????????????????????????????3??????????????????????????????????????3??????????????????????$??????4?????????????? ??????????????????????????????????4??????????????????????????????????????4??????????????    ????????$??????5??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????5??????????????????????????????????????5??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????6??????????????????????$??????7??????????????????????????????????????????$??????8????????????????????????????????????????????????8??????????????????????????????????????8??????????????????????$??????9?????????????? ??????????????????????????????????9??????????????????????????????????????9??????????????    ????????$??????:??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????:??????????????????????????????????????:??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????;??????????????????????$??????<??????????????????????????????????????????$??????=????????????????????????????????????????????????=??????????????????????????????????????=??????????????????????$??????>?????????????? ??????????????????????????????????>??????????????????????????????????????>??????????????    ????????$?????????????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????@??????????????????????$??????A??????????????????????????????????????????$??????B????????????????????????????????????????????????B??????????????????????????????????????B??????????????????????$??????C?????????????? ??????????????????????????????????C??????????????????????????????????????C??????????????    ????????$??????D??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????D??????????????????????????????????????D??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????E??????????????????????$??????F??????????????????????????????????????????$??????G????????????????????????????????????????????????G??????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ????????????????????????????G??????????????????????$??????H??????????????   ??????????????????????????????????H??????????????????????????????????????H??????????????    ????????$??????I??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????I??????????????????????????????????????I??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????J??????????????????????$??????K??????????????????????????????????????????$??????L????????????????????????????????????????????????L??????????????????????????????????????L??????????????????????$??????M?????????????? ??????????????????????????????????M??????????????????????????????????????M??????????????    ????????$??????N??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????N??????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ????????????????????????????N??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????O??????????????????????$??????P??????????????????????????????????????????$??????Q????????????????????????????????????????????????Q??????????????????????????????????????Q??????????????????????$??????R?????????????? ??????????????????????????????????R??????????????????????????????????????R??????????????    ????????$??????S??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????S??????????????????????????????????????S??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????T??????????????????????$??????U??????????????????????????????????????????$??????V????????????????????????????????????????????????V??????????????????????????????????????V??????????????????????$??????W?????????????? ??????????????????????????????????W??????????????????????????????????????W??????????????    ????????$??????X??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????X??????????????????????????????????????X??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????Y??????????????????????$??????Z??????????????????????????????????????????$??????[????????????????????????????????????????????????[??????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ????????????????????????????[??????????????????????$??????\??????????????   ??????????????????????????????????\??????????????????????????????????????\??????????????    ????????$??????]??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????]??????????????????????????????????????]??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????^??????????????????????$??????_??????????????????????????????????????????$??????`????????????????????????????????????????????????`??????????????????????????????????????`??????????????????????$??????a?????????????? ??????????????????????????????????a??????????????????????????????????????a??????????????    ????????$??????b??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????b??????????????????????????????????????b??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????c??????????????????????$??????d??????????????????????????????????????????$??????e????????????????????????????????????????????????e??????????????????????????????????????e??????????????????????$??????f?????????????? ??????????????????????????????????f??????????????????????????????????????f??????????????    ????????$??????g??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????g??????????????????????????????????????g??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????h??????????????????????$??????i??????????????????????????????????????????$??????j????????????????????????????????????????????????j??????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ????????????????????????????j??????????????????????$??????k??????????????   ??????????????????????????????????k??????????????????????????????????????k??????????????    ????????$??????l??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????????????????????????l??????????????????????????????????????l??????????????
06-08 13:47:51.830: I/System.out(2334): ??????????????m????????????????????????????n????????????????????????????o????????????????????????????p??????????????????????
```

I'll attempt to figure out why the XML I read in from the stream was total gibberish....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, apparently my debug senses managed to get me in the right direction.

So apparently reading the data with

```
 br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/xml/levels.xml")));
```

was a Terrible idea. The solution was to put the XML files into the /res/raw folder, and open them as raw resource.

```
    public LevelManager(Context context)
    {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        Levels levels = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.levels)));
            levels = serializer.read(Levels.class, br);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error in deserialization.", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (br != null)
            {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(br);
            }
        }
```

This way, the content of the file was properly read.

I hope this will help someone in the future, and hopefully not just clogging up SO with a question I resolved after 20 minutes :D

EDIT:
Also, I needed to add

```
@Root
public class Levels
{

@ElementList(type=Level.class, inline=true)
private List<Level> levels;

public Levels()
{

}

public Levels(@ElementList(name = "levels", type=Level.class, inline=true) List<Level> levels)
{
    this.levels = levels;
}


public List<Level> getLevels()
{
    return levels;
}

public void setLevels(List<Level> levels)
{
    this.levels = levels;
    }
}
```

inline=true because otherwise it couldn't find the data according to my XML structure. But that wasn't really related to the issue.