# Using enums to pass data to listviews

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, enums

I'm attempting to use multiple enums that I've set as subclasses to a master class as the data source for listviews on separate fragments.
Each fragment will have two listviews, but each listview will only need to use certain parts of the data. Each enum has two strings "name" and "abbr" and a double "value".
I would like to set both strings as the ListView titles, and use the value in a calculation.

`Listview1` will hold titles, abbrs, and one `EditText` in the center row. `Listview2` will hold titles, abbrs, and one more `TextView` that will update based on the `EditText` input and the value from the enum. I realize I will need two custom adapters for this, one for the heterogeneous `Listview1`, and one for `Listview2`. 
I am a little lost on implementing, and have only attempted doing the custom adapter for `Listview2`.

I have tried looking at multiple SO questions, and listview tutorials that use database models and then have tried to use that but with my static enum lists, but am just a bit lost. Any help from a high level approach, specifics, or a nice tutorial would be much appreciated. I am probably not even close on the right path as I am new at Android and relatively new at OOP, thanks for bearing with the poor code!

What I have so far (I set up a test project, which is why I have this listview inflated in main as opposed to in a fragment - if there are any issues with this besides switching the context let me know):

Enum class holding all enums

```
public class Enums {

public enum Pressures{
    ITEM1        ("name", "abbr", 1.0),
    etc...;

    private final String name;
    private final String abbr;
    private final double value;

    Pressures(String name, String abbr, double value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.abbr = abbr;
        this.intermediary = intermediary;
    }

    public String getNames() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAbbr() {
        return abbr;
    }

    public double getIntermediary() {
        return intermediary;
    }
}

public enum Enum2 {
...
}
}
```

Custom Adapter for `Listview2`:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Enums.Pressures> pressureEnum;


public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, List<Enums.Pressures> units) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.pressureEnum = units;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pressureEnum.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return pressureEnum.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView abbr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.abbr);

    Enums.Pressures p = pressureEnum.get(position);

    name.setText(p.getNames());
    abbr.setText(p.getAbbr());

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Main:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

//This List was a poor attempt at setting the list from the enum
//I don't believe ArrayList is the proper choice as I have an enum object
//but I'm not quite sure what to use
private List<Enums.Pressures> pressureUnits = new ArrayList<Enums.Pressures>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, pressureUnits);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `Enums.Pressures.values();` which returns all Pressures in an array of `Enums.Pressures[]`? You will still need a custom adapter though. I'm surprised you can access `Enums.Pressures` like that without it being specified as `public static enum` though.

Comment: @Zhu Enums in Java are by default static and do not need to be declared static. One thing I do know from my research into them! Also, thanks for the reply. I knew I was overlooking something simple.

Comment: Oh I see, that explains why you have access to it then. I'd still rather use the `Enums.Pressures.values()` if you need to display all the data in the enums, rather than the list (which, by the way, is empty as it doesn't seem initialized by anything).

Comment: @Zhu Thanks, I realize it was empty now. Will I run into any issues if I just want to display certain data fields as opposed to all of the data that each enum has?

Comment: well technically `values()` gives you every enum value of the specific enum in an array, so if you need to limit how many you display, you should probably stick to the list and just initialize it with whichever is needed.

Comment: something like `private List<Enums.Pressures> pressureUnits = new ArrayList<Enums.Pressures>(Arrays.toList(Enums.Pressures.values()));` should work for now.

Comment: @Zhu Thanks for the example. I will implement and see if it fits my needs. One reason I chose enums for this was so that I could pass all the data associated with the item, then use some to set titles and other static things, and use other data such as doubles to use in a dynamic context with a TextWatcher. Do you have any experience with that or should I just initialize title arrays, and then associate the doubles from the array index? Thanks again for all your help, I am learning a lot.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I'm not sure this is the best possible approach :) In fact I don't think it should be an `enum` to begin with. I think this should be stored in XML files and loaded into classes using SimpleXML, like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106734/simplexml-throws-xmlpullparserexception-unterminated-entity-ref-for-no-reason

Comment: but to be honest, I can't completely fore-see the effects of using an enum.

Comment: @Zhu Understandable. I am looking more into using XML to store the data, but for the sake of consistency in my code, I may just use the enums to store the static information, and programmatically add the dynamic information to a default blank TextView. Thanks again, it is always good to bounce ideas off of someone more experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Your List "pressureUnits" is empty. You've specified that it is a list of Pressures but not added anything to it. Usually this is done with the "add" method, i.e. pressureUnits.add(...).

However what I think you want to use is Enums.Pressures.values(). This will return an array containing each of your enum elements. Then you will be able to create an adapter using that array. If you can't do it with the BaseAdapter you are using now, have a look at using the ArrayAdapter class rather than the BaseAdapter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Would I use the .values() method within the enum class and store it in an array to be called? Or would I use the method in my main class?

Comment: In the main class, instead of the List<Enums.Pressures> you have now. The values() method with give you the array.