# How to deserialize an xml representing a root-level array with Simple Xml Framework

Tags: java, xml, deserialization, simple-framework

I am using [Simple XML framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) for deserialization on Android.

The xml that I need to deserialize is roughly like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elements type="array">
    <element foo="x"/>
    <element foo="y"/>
</elements>
```

In other words, it is an array right on the root level.

How to define a model class that I can deserialize it to?

I tried something as follows:

```
@Root (name = "elements")
public class Elements implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = ...

   @ElementArray (name = "element")
   private List<Element> elements;
}
```

But it fails, since there is no `type` field to account for the `type` attribute in the xml.

Adding a `type` field (just for the sake of satisfying the deserializer) doesn't resolve the issue, generates another error instead: `org.simpleframework.xml.core.InstantiationException: Type is not an array interface java.util.List for field 'elements' ...`

What's the proper way of implementing the `Elements` class? Even though under time pressure, I'd like a clean solution, not some hackish workaround (that I'd probably come up with).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106734/simplexml-throws-xmlpullparserexception-unterminated-entity-ref-for-no-reason here is a working setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is:

```
public class Elements implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = ...

   @Attribute (name = "type", required = false)
   private String type;

   @ElementList (name = "elements", entry = "element", inline = true)
   private List<Element> elements;
}
```

`J. Marcos`'s answer was correct in pointing out that I should have used `ElementList` and the `inline` attribute.

What was still missing is removing the `Root` annotation (I guess it clashes with the idea of inlining the list), and adding an `entry` attribute, which specifies the name of the array element.

Perhaps it is not required if the tag is of the same name as the field (like in my contrived example), but if they differ (say, `elementItem` in the class and `element_item` in the xml), it apparently is.

Answer (score 1):

In your Elements class, you should use `@ElementList` and add an attribute named "type"

```
@ElementList(name="elements", inline=true)
private List<Element> elements;

@Attribute(name="type")
private String type;
```

Also, if you don't wanna bother about the `type` attribute in the xml, just add `required=false`, like this:

```
@Attribute(name="type", required=false)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it tomorrow and accept your answer.