# Using Simple Framework to deserializing a simple XML in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

So I'm trying to use the [Simple Framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to deserialize a simple xml in java. My xml is a huge piece of data, of which I'm posting only the part thats causing me issues.

```
<item>
<title>Awesome Title</title>

<link>https://awesome_link</link>

<description>Awesome very very long
Description
</description>

<category domain="https://awesome_domain>Awesome Category 1</category>

<category domain="https://awesome_domain”>Awesome Category 2</category>

<category domain="https://awesome_domain”>Awesome Category 3</category>

<category domain="https://awesome_domain”>Awesome Category 4</category>

<pubDate>Wed, 17 Sep 2014 17:57:50 GMT</pubDate>

<author>Awesome author</author>

<guid>Awesome GUID</guid>

<dc:date>Awesome Date</dc:date>

<clearspace:dateToText>3 hours, 35 minutes ago</clearspace:dateToText>

<clearspace:objectType>0</clearspace:objectType>

</item>
```

For the above, I have created a sample JAVA class called Item that looks something like this

```
@Root
public class Item {

    @Element
    private String title;

    @Element
    private String link;

    @Element
    private String description;

    // @ElementMap(entry = "category", key = "domain", attribute = true, inline
    // = true)
    // private Map<String, String> map;

    @ElementList(entry = "category", inline = true, type = String.class)
    private List<String> categoryList;

    @Element
    private String pubDate;

    @Element
    private String author;

    @Element
    private String guid;

    @Element
    private String date;

    @Element
    private String dateToText;

    @Element
    private String objectType;
}
```

But I am getting the following error

```
com.android.volley.VolleyError: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false, empty=true, entry=category, inline=true, name=, required=true, type=class java.lang.String) on field 'categoryList' private java.util.List com.xx.xx.Item.categoryList for class com.xx.xx.xx.Item at line 210
```

I've spent almost 2 hours now on this. Anyone has any idea as to what I am doing wrong? I also tried with an ElementMap as seen in the comment, but that didnt work either.

**UPDATE**
I also tried with creating a separate Category class as follows

```
@Root
public class Category {

    @Attribute
    protected String domain;

    @Text
    private String value;

}
```

And changing my categoryList object in the Item class as follows

```
@ElementList(entry = "category", inline = true, type = Category.class)
private List<Category> categoryList;
```

But in vain! :(

**UPDATE**
Even this didnt work!

```
@ElementList(inline=true)
private List<Category> categoryList;
```

Comment: what is line 210? is it `<dc:date>Awesome Date</dc:date>`?

Comment: There is no line 210 in any of my file. I posted the entire file content above. I think that line number is pointing to the Simple library somewhere. I'm not facing problem in the date part. I am unable to get the categories list.

Comment: oh. well I had a SimpleXML question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106734/simplexml-throws-xmlpullparserexception-unterminated-entity-ref-for-no-reason , I think the problem has to do with the fact that `category` has a `domain` attribute and thus it cannot be made into a `String`, and you should have your own `Category` class for it. I also had a tag that wrapped the list, I don't know if that was truly necessary or not, but it worked for me.

Comment: @Zhuinden Thanks for the reply. But I even tried that. Check my updated question.

Comment: Can't you wrap the `Category` elements into a `Categories` tag, and create a class for the `Categories` which contains the inline list? Just wondering how static the XML is.

Comment: @Zhuinden I'm afraid I cannot do that, as its a huge data that is coming from the server and I don't think that it can change.

Comment: Figured. This should be case http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#inline ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61496/discussion-between-antrromet-and-zhuinden).