# Save Game data - Java

Tags: java, save

I've created a rudimentary game with a few objects. I'd like to give the user of the program the ability to save and load the state of the program.

I've researched multiple articles and read through a lot of overstack posts. I was surprised by the amount of methods, and the complexity of each of those methods.

Most methods require that I create the framework or skeleton of all objects that I want to save, and then load them line by line, calling each object manually, and then casting it back into its data type and class.

Yes, I'm new to programming. But I'm not asking for a handout. I'm asking for a concise explanation.

I read the below article, as I explored the idea of outputting to an XML file.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/

As I stated, I'm new to programming. Should I be learning XML in tandem with Java?

My question is the following:

A) Doesn't my IDE, upon successful compilation, know how many objects I have, their data type, and what class they belong to?

B) Is there a way to save ALL objects without specifying them individually.

c) Have I overdramitized the complexity of saving a simple program?

Comment: Save and load the program? Save the objects? It's unclear what you are asking about. Do you want to save an object to a file?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html)

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I want to save the game. I want the user to be able to save the game, leave for a day, come back, and load their game where they started, with all objects full intact.

Comment: You can either use XML or JSON for serialization of data into text. You could also use `Serializable` interface and `ObjectOutputStream` into bytecode(?), but JSON is more reliable. If you have a collective `GameModel` class that contains all existing entities that are relevant to the current game state, then you could serialize that one class, and all others would be serialized recursively.

Comment: @gtgaxiola so then...I haven't overdramatized the functionality of saving stuff in java, or really any language.

Comment: no. This is quite normal, unless you are saving to DB. Albeit I will go with @EpicPandaForce suggestion.

Comment: @JosephErickson I am not sure if serialization is good approach here. You may be better off just converting your game state into some text (e.g. in JSON format) and then loading it back. So your game would have two ways to initialize it: 1. no parameters - default 2. String/JsonObject/File - loaded state.

Comment: You didn't overcomplicate it, although most serializers are capable of recursively saving all elements within a given class. For example, I had a question here where everything was set up pretty well for `SimpleXML` library which does all the class-XML mapping magic in the background: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24106867/2413303

Comment: If you dont want to do to much, you can create a class that holds all your data (all necessary variables that need to be safed) and store it using the reflection api: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I guess the answer is, it's absolutely as overwhelming as I thought. Sounds like I'm going  to be watching some youtube on how to convert game state to JSON

Comment: @JosephErickson good plan, although as I said, if you specify the annotations right for `SimpleXML` (XML) or `Jackson` (JSON) or maybe even `JSONBeans`  https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/jsonbeans (designed specifically for games, if I remember correctly - same as the one provided by LibGDX framework!), then you can just give it one `GameState` object and the data will be saved recursively for all of its elements.

Comment: Actually, you should just go with `JSONBeans`. It does EXACTLY what you want. I'll link again: https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/jsonbeans

Comment: I haven't used JSONBeans, but can really recommend XStream if you want an easy Bean -> Object conversion. You could save the state in a one-liner. Not saying it is the best solution, but a reasonable one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I be learning XML in tandem with Java?

There's no reason to unless you want to learn XML or think XML is a good option for your application. There are many ways to serialize without XML.

> Doesn't my IDE, upon succesful compilation, know how many objects I have, their data type, and what class they belong to?

No, it doesn't have to. Since allocations are done dynamically in Java, there are situations where it's even impossible to know this information statically.

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[ new Scanner(System.in).nextInt() ];
for(int i = 0; i < foos.length; ++i)
    foos[i] = new Foo();
```

(How many `Foo`s were created? The compiler doesn't know.)

Certainly the compiler knows a lot about the *types* of data.

> B) Is there a way to save ALL objects without specifying them individually.

Maybe with Serializable. Basically you will put all your program state inside a single object. When you serialize that single object, everything else gets serialized recursively.

```
class FooState implements Serializable {
    Integer a, b, c; // Integer and String
    String d, e, f;  // also implement Serializable
}

class Foo {
    static FooState allMyState = new FooState();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(new File("myFile.data")))) {
            // no need to specify members individually
            oos.writeObject(allMyState);
        }
    }
}
```

The same concept probably applies to other serialization schemes like JSON, XML, etc.

You need to think carefully about what you put in the state object since everything in it will get saved.

> c) Have I overdramitized the complexity of saving a simple program?

Not really. Saving program state can be complicated if it's not just a few values.

Answer (score 2):

**A) Doesn't my IDE, upon succesful compilation, know how many objects I have, their data type, and what class they belong to?**

Loading the state of the program has nothing to do with IDE or compilation. You start your program and it's already running, you want to change it's state by loading some state from the file.

If you use serialization, you may face problems related to versions and classes incompatibility - e.g. if you decide to add a new field to a class, you will need to write extra code to be able to load an older state, which didn't have that field. So other format such as XML, JSON or plain text (and doing the conversion yourself) may be better idea.

**B) Is there a way to save ALL objects without specifying them individually.**

Well, theoretically it should be possible to save the state of entire JVM and load it back later. It's an advanced topic and there would be a lot of problems because of all clever stuff going on inside JVM (such as Just-In-Time compiler, garbage collection and various on-the-fly optimizations). I don't recommend going down this way. Most probably, you won't be able to change your code at all - e.g. if you add new button in your GUI, the loaded version will not have it, because it will be loading old versions of the classes. So it won't be possible to load an old game state into new version of the game.

**C) Have I overdramitized the complexity of saving a simple program?**

Let's say that your game has class called `Game` with constructor `Game(String name)` (and some other parameters). For the first time, you can create it by just calling `new Game("firstGame")`. But now you want to create this object from some saved state. You can either serialize the object and then load it back, the result will be the object itself. Or you can read the file to get that string and just call the constructor yourself using this string. Going further this way there are libraries that can convert object to JSON and JSON to object (such as Jackson serializer).

Answer (score 0):

Have a class that can save the current state of the game.

```
public class Game{
    int coOrdinateX;
    int coOrdinateY;
    int score;
    String[] powersCurrentlyTheUserHad;
    ...
}
```

when ever user exits, load this class with relevant data. As once the game terminates, memory vanishes, you need to save this in a file.

Serialization is a way of storing Objects to disk(essentially into files), such that, when you de-serialize using the library functions, you directly get back the object with the current state.

check 
 http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm for more details